# Changing HTML DOM element name dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml

What I'm thinking about is when I remove or add a child element from the DOM, I will change other elements' names through JavaScript or jQuery.  For example, I'm going to remove the second text box from a form which have 3 text boxes.  They have the names "input-1", "input-2" and "input-3."  After removing "input-2," I'm going to rename "input-3" as "input-2".  Then, when I'm going to add a new text box, it will be named "input-3."  Is this efficient?

Comment: what is your html markup?... and why would you do that?...

Comment: Can you expand why you want to do this.  It doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: I like to do this so that I can bind the form values to a model.  I'm using ASP.NET MVC on the server-side.  If I can't do this thing, I need to do several lines of code to manipulate the form values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just change the elements' names before the form is submitted to the server. No need for dynamic changing, i.e., when an element is removed and and a new one is added. It's more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

what is your html markup?... and why would you do that?...

```
$('input:text').attr('name',function(index,name){
   return 'input-' + (index+1);
   // this will rename input's of type text based on their indices..
});
```